# Class Method not working in objective c

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, methods, instance

In my code I have a class called 'ProfileShareViewController', In which I have imported another class I have created called 'OwnProfileData', And I have also created an Instance of that class (class = OwnProfileData) as a property Of 'ProfileShareViewController' and synthesized it (instance called 'OwnProfile').

In another class I have called 'EditProfileViewController', I have imported the 'ProfileShareViewController', and now I am trying to change a property of the OwnProfile object from the ProfileShareViewController within the EditProfileViewController class.

For some reason that doesn't work. I have Tried typing:

```
[[ProfileShareViewController ownProfile] setName:@"Ido"];
```

(The property I am trying to set is Name, and as it is synthesized in OwnProfileData, I am using 'setName').
This doesn't work and I get the warning: "No known class method for selector 'ownMethod'.

Any Idea as for why that might happen and how I can fix this?

Thanks for your comments! Any support is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an instance of `ProfileShareViewController`, because `ownProfile` is an instance property, not an class method. Read about the differences between classes and instances.

Or did I misunderstood smth?

Comment: But if its a view controller class in an iOS app, what is the instance of to? or do I just create a random one?